# How can I use ipfw to duplicate the effects of OS X's Little Snitch

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ipfw

I'd like to know exactly what is leaving my laptop and going on the wire.

I used to use Little Snitch for this, but apparently it's possible to do the same thing with ipfw.

How would I go about doing this?

Running OS X 10.6.4.

Comment: [For reference](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). I suggest you edit your question title to something likie "use ipfw to show what processes are making connections".

Comment: I think Andrew is right. `ipfw` exists on more than just Mac OS, but Little Snitch is exclusive to Mac OS. You might get better (or faster) answers that way.

Comment: Ipfw is totally the tool to use.

Comment: @Andrew,zneak  I agree, but little snitch is alone as far as functionality offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the tcpdump command to see your network traffic

www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

open Terminal.app and type

```
sudo tcpdump -i en1
```

en1 should be your wireless port, and en0 is usually your ethernet port

type `ifconfig` for a list

To use ipfw, I believe you add a logging clause to your rules. When a packet matches a rule, it will be logged. Its been years since I've use ipfw, so you best check the manual:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html
or type `man ipfw` into Terminal.app